# Minkowski Inequality for $p \le 1$

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

I've been trying to prove the concavity of a particular function which I reduced to proving the reverse Minkowski Inequality for $p \le 1$, $p \ne 0$ for arguments in $\mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}$.  That is,

$$
\|x \|_p + \|y\|_p \le \|x+y\|_p
$$

I've found a proof for the case of $0 < p \le 1$, but the case when $p < 0$ still evades me.  All proofs of Minkowski's Inequality (in the proper direction) usually rely on Hölder's Inequality, which in turn relies on Young's Inequality.  However, Young's does not apply for exponents below $0$, and I am rather jammed up finding another way.  Can anyone offer a little direction?

Comment: Isn't that false, at the very least for $p=1$? Together with the usual Minkowski inequality you deduce that $$ \| x+y \| _p = |\ x\|_p + \| y \|_p ,$$ which is false generally.

Comment: Quite right you are if either $x,y < 0$.  I've amended it to only consider values with elements greater than or equal to 0.

Answer (score 31):

Let $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ be two elements of $\mathbb{R}^n_{+}$. Using the concavity of the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=x^p$, $0<p<1$, we have for any $t\in (0,1)$: $$(x_k+y_k)^p=\bigg(t\dfrac{x_k}{t}+(1-t)\dfrac{y_k}{1-t}\bigg)^p\geq  t\dfrac{x_k^p}{t^p}+(1-t)\dfrac{y_k^p}{(1-t)^p}.$$
 Taking the sum, we obtain $$||x+y||_p^p\geq  t\dfrac{||x||_p^p}{t^p}+(1-t)\dfrac{||y||_p^p}{(1-t)^p}.$$
If $t=\dfrac{||x||_p}{||x||_p+||y||_p}$ then $1-t=\dfrac{||y||_p}{||x||_p+||y||_p}$ and we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
||x+y||_p^p &\geq& t\dfrac{||x||_p^p}{\dfrac{||x||_p^p}{\bigg(||x||_p+||y||_p\bigg)^p}}+(1-t)\dfrac{||y||_p^p}{\dfrac{||y||_p^p}{\bigg(||x||_p+||y||_p\bigg)^p}}\\
\Rightarrow ||x+y||_p^p &\geq& t\bigg(||x||_p+||y||_p\bigg)^p+(1-t)\bigg(||x||_p+||y||_p\bigg)^p=\bigg(||x||_p+||y||_p\bigg)^p\\
 \Rightarrow||x+y||_p &\geq& ||x||_p+||y||_p.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: This is also a nice idea for a different proof of Minkowski's inequality in the case $1 \le p < \infty$.

Comment: But if we take $x=-y$ , with $\|y\|_p\neq 0$ , we'd have that $\|-y+y\|_p \geq 2 \|y\|_p \implies 0 \geq  \|y\|_p \implies \|y\|_p=0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @stat_yale f(x) is only well-defined (and concave) for positive values of x.

Comment: @domath I have the question as yours. Do you know how to explain the case when $\mathbf{x}=-\mathbf{y}$ with $\|\mathbf{y}\|_p\neq0$?

Comment: @suineg We are talking about vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ (vectors with positive components).

Answer (score 6):

Hölder is reversed when $p<0$. The proof is a simple change of variables. See Bullen's book "Handbook of Means and Their Inequalities" p.202-3 for details. Hence Minkowski is also reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Jax's answer actually solved OP's problem. He missed only one small thing, we can take off the power $p$ because we take power of $1/p$. When $p\in (0,1)$, the function $x^{\frac{1}{p}}$ is increasing, and thus taking the power still gives you the same direction of the inequality, hence the proof.

This observation is the key to solve the case of $p<0$. When $p<0$, the function $x^{p}$ is convex, so we can do exactly the same thing but with the inequality sign reversed, i.e. everything is pretty much the same, instead, we use convexity, and we get $$\|\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\|_{p}^{p}\leq (\|\mathbf{x}\|_{p}+\|\mathbf{y}\|_{p})^{p}.$$ This time, when you take of the power, note that the function $x^{\frac{1}{p}}$ is decreasing, because $p<0$. Hence, taking $\frac{1}{p}$-power both side reverses the inequality, and thus $$\|\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\|_{p}\geq (\|\mathbf{x}\|_{p}+\|\mathbf{y}\|_{p}).$$