# $\lVert x \rVert_p = \left (|x_1|^p + ... + |x_n|^p \right)^{1/p}$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $p \geq 1$. Why assume that $p \geq 1?$

Tags: normed-spaces

Is this because the Minkowski inequality fails for $0 < p < 1?$ In fact, is Minkowski inequality false for $0 < p < 1?$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, it fails for $0<p<1$.

Comment: Nice. Thanks @geetha290krm

Answer (score 0):

Take $p \in (0,1)$. Then for instance, in the two-dimensional case,

$$\|(1,0) + (0,1)\|_p = \|(1,1)\|_p = 2^{1/p}$$

but

$$\|(1,0)\|_p = \|(0,1)\|_p = 1$$

The triangle inequality requires, therefore, that

$$2^{1/p} \le 1+1 = 2$$

However, with $0<p<1$, then $1/p > 1$ and $2^{1/p} > 2^1 = 2$.

That is to say, the triangle inequality does not hold for $p \in (0,1)$, so you don't have a norm.

---

However, for $p \in (0,1)$, the reverse case holds in general for $p$-"norms":  that is, Minkowski's inequality can be said to be

$$\|x+y\|_p \ge \|x\|_p + \|y\|_p$$

in the case $p \in (0,1)$. A standard argument (according to Wikipedia) uses the analogous reversal for Holder's inequality in this range; other discussion on this "reversed Minkowski" inequality is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73294/minkowski-inequality-for-p-le-1) on MSE.