# An inverse Minkowski inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

For a non-negative sequence of real numbers $t_1, \dotsc, t_n$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n t_i = 1$ and $r\neq 0$, define $M_r(a) = (\sum_{i=1}^n t_i a_i^r)^{1/r}$ ($a = (a_1, \dotsc, a_n)$ non-negative). Show that if $r < 0 < s < t$ and $1/r + 1/s = 1/t$ then
$$M_t(ab) \geq M_r(a)M_s(b)\ ,$$
for nonnegative sequences $a,b$, where $ab = (a_1b_1, \dotsc, a_nb_n)$. Deduce that if $0 < r < 1$ then
$$ M_r(a+b) \geq M_r(a)+M_r(b)\ .$$

---

The above is exercise 15, chapter 1, of Bollobás's Linear Analysis book. The first statement is simple enough to show. The second statement is that proven in, for example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73294/minkowski-inequality-for-p-le-1). However, whenever Bollobás says "deduce", there has thus far always been a very immediate way to obtain the next statement from what has been established thus far (if not always easy to see), and here, I very much cannot see it. Any suggestions for how to do this *deduction* (rather than prove it from scratch, which is not an issue)?

Comment: how is $M_r$ defined for negative $r ?$ You specified in the beginning that $r>0.$

Comment: also what is $ab$ for two vectors ?

Comment: Defined the same as for $r>0$, and the latter is an elementwise product. Will edit when I'm by a computer.

Comment: ok. Generally, Holder implies Minkowski for $p>1$ and is easily derived. So I imagine one could mimic the idea to reproduce a similar proof for $p<1.$

Comment: Yes that was indeed what I attempted. Maybe I just made a mess of it.

Comment: (specifically, I'm sure there will be some nice picks for $r,s,t$ that make this just drop out, but I don't see them)

Comment: Ah, maybe I need to take $b=1/b'$ for another non neg sequence $b'$ and relabel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$M_p^p(a+b) = \sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)^p = \sum_{i=1}^na_i(a_i+b_i)^{p-1}+\sum_{i=1}^nb_i(a_i+b_i)^{p-1}=M_t^t(a^{1/t},(a+b)^{(p-1)/t}) + M_t^t(b^{1/t},(a+b)^{(p-1)/t}).$$
But
$$M_t(a^{1/t},(a+b)^{(p-1)/t})\geq M_r(a^{1/t})M_s((a+b)^{(p-1)/t})$$
and so:
$$M_p^p(a+b)\geq\left(M_r^t(a^{1/t})+M_r^t(b^{1/t})\right)M_s^t((a+b)^{(p-1)/t})$$
with $r<0<s<t$ and $\frac 1t = \frac 1s+\frac 1r.$ Now, just take $t=1$ and $r=p$, which gives $s = \dfrac{p}{p-1}<0$ and it simplifies to:
$$M_p^p(a+b)\geq(M_p(a)+M_p(b))M_p^{p-1}(a+b)$$
and we are done. Note that I did not bother to include the weight variables since they don't really affect anything, or just think of a finite, counting measure. Also, I used $p$ since $r,p,s$ are reserved for the inequality we are going to use.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to take $t=1$ and got very tangled.

Comment: yeah interpolation inequalities in general is very annoying like that. Also,it looks like I switched $r$ and $s$.